DS1307 RTC Time Drift
Do you Know, how much the tolerance of ds1307 RTC is per day?
Most importantly, is this time tolerance a fix value or it has random error. Can we fix this problem with code?
Edit: By the recommendation of some people, I added caps to the crystal to decrease this drift.
By adding 15 pf caps to the crystal(However it was suggested 12.5pf but I could not find such in the market of my country) it showed different behavior but it is not still accurate. Without 15 pf caps, ds1307 was about 20 seconds faster per week. Then I made two circuits on bread board by 15pf caps. After one week one of them was 12 seconds slower and another one was 18 second slower.
Do you have any suggestion or circuit schematic, How can I decrease this drift of ds1307?
By the way this the circuit of mine before adding 15pf caps.


Did you read Application Note 58 like suggested in the datasheet?

If you want real accurate RTC it is better to use DS3231 (60s per year) instead of DS1307.

You already have an answer. Adding caps is the wrong solution, and I already said that. The chip already contains capacitors in it. You must select a correct crystal which is compatible with the RTC chip.

Replace your crystal for more precise one, temperature compensated if possible. DTCXO stands for Digitally Temperature-Compensated Crystal Oscillator. For example Epson’s TG-3541CE achieves accuracy of < ±3.4 ppm from -40 to +85 degC or < ±8 ppm up to +105 degC, equivalent to only± 9 or± 21 seconds time error per month respectively. I am not sure if it is compatible with DS1307. This solution is still worse than using DS3231.

The DS1307 is perfectly accurate, because the precision does not depend on it.
It depends on which crystal you connect to it and how well you designed the PCB.
You can fix everything in code but then you must know the imperfections of your whole design, like in which way your circuit is sensitive to supply voltage, temperature, crystal initial accuracy and aging.

I have taken all issues into consideration in PCB design but I have not used any caps for crystal.
How can we fix it by code while the drift is not fix. It is sometimes + and sometimes -.

@Saeed There should be no caps at all, as they are included inside the chip. What you need is a correctly designed PCB and crystal with correct parameters to run correctly with this chip. If it goes too fast and too slow, there might be many problems instead of just one.
